# Busybox equivalent for bashrc

Tags: bash, login, busybox

I use a number of docker containers where the author chose busybox, which is linked to `/bin/sh`.

Is there an equivalent in busybox for `.bashrc` or `.profile`?

If so, where should it be located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is answered pretty well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025686/15375140

Essentially `/bin/sh` is not a login shell, so it is not going to source `.profile` by default. You can alter the Dockerfile to have it source your `.profile` manually, or execute `/bin/sh -l` instead.

Unfortunately both of those options require modifying the source image, which is somewhat undesirable in many cases. It does appear that you can tell it to source a profile by putting your profile script into the ENV environment variable like `ENV=~/.shrc` -- and that means all you need to do is modify your docker commandline (or docker-compose, or whatever else is launching your container). For example, for `docker run` you would add the parameter `-e ENV='~/.shrc'`